# React Native Firebase Analytics get User Country

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, firebase-analytics, react-native-firebase

**Problem**

I want to get the user's current country in React Native to find out if they're in the EU so I can display a GDPR consent form to collect personal data for advertising purposes.

I don't want to have to ask the user to allow location services as my app doesn't need to have their current location.

I have React Native Firebase installed in my app and I noticed that Analytics will tell me the users country in my console.

Does anyone know how I can access the user's country via React Native Firebase Analytics in my JS code?

If anyone has a better way to get the user's country I'm open to that as well!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11055065/how-to-determine-clients-country-using-google-analytics

Answer (score 1):

Google Analytics for Firebase automatically derives the location of the user from a number of data points, mostly from the IP address from which they connect. There is no API to get that information from Analytics.

Most applications that need this information use a similar IP-to-location lookup API to determine it, or inspect the phone settings for the user.